# Confirmation message on a custom link

Tags: apex

I have a custom link I created and added to the home page.  It's a javascript link and it starts a batch process.  What I would like to do is give the user a confirmation dialog like

```
var rtn = confirm('Do you really want to do this?')
if(rtn)
   sforce.apex.execute('myclass','mymethod',{});
```

but I get an error that says confirm is not defined?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, @user4978.  I surrounded your code in a code format block so that it would show up the way that you typed it in.  Your code looks alright to me.  Perhaps you could try `window.confirm`?

Comment: Which browsers have you tried? can you try with a HTML component `<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')){alert('batch submission goes here');}">click</a>`?